# Cannot POST /api/auth/registration - problem with server

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

So, I learn backend, and make a cloud app. I want to explore my server on registration. It`s work on POST only, but there is already bugs. I try Postman to check request, and I get a mistake there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /api/auth/registration</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

my code:
index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth.routes')

const app = express();
const PORT = config.get('serverPort');
app.use('api/auth', authRouter)

const start = async() => {
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(config.get('DbUrl'))
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('listening on port', PORT)
        })
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

auth.routes.js:

```
const Router = require('express')
const User = require('../module/User')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator')

const routes = new Router();

routes.post('/registration',
        [
            check('email', 'Incorrect email').isEmail(),
            check('password', 'must be longer than 3 and shorter than 13 symb').isLength({min: 3, max: 13})
        ],
         async (res, req) => {
            try{
                const errors = validationResult(req)
                if(!errors.isEmpty()){
                    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Incorrect request', errors})
                }

                const {email, password} = res.body;
                const candidate = User.findOne({email})
            
                if(candidate){
                    return res.status(400).json({message: 'User already registered'})
                }
            
                const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 15)
                const user = new User({email, password: hashPassword})
            
                await user.save()
                return res.status(200).json({message: 'User was created successfully'})
            } catch (e){

            }
})

module.exports = routes
```

User.js:

```
const {model, Schema} = require("mongoose");


const User = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    diskSpace: {type: Number, default: 1024**3*10},
    usedSpace: {type: Number, default: 0},
    avatar: {type: String},
    files: [{type: Object, ref: 'File'}]
})

module.exports = model('User', User)
```

I try to do smth, but nothing isn't help.Could u help me with that? I don`t understand, what I have to do

Comment: Post the error here so we can see the problem.

Comment: Try to add `/` before 'api/auth' -> `app.use('/api/auth',.......`

Comment: Postman doesn`t send the problem. I even don't know, what I have to change in my code. So, console doesn't see a problem

Comment: I tried this( `app.use('/api/auth/, ....)`, but request didn't send

Comment: You may have server logs available to check to help you narrow down the problem.